# How to use Livewire component inside of javascript?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Looking at docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#from-js
working with Livewire component inside of javascript

```
<script>
    Livewire.emit('postAdded')
</script>
```

I do not see what  Livewire is ? Declared var ? How can I get it.
I need from JS code get value of some var and run component method.
How can I do it?

**Modified Block  # 2:**

Defining in template of my component :

```
<div class="admin_page_container" id="facilities_admin_page_container">
   ...
```

In method of my alpinejs component I do

```
function adminFacilitiesComponent() {
    return {
        getSubmitLabel: function (component) {
            const doc = document.getElementById("facilities_admin_page_container");
            console.log('doc::')
            console.log(doc)

            var updateMode = window.livewire.find(doc.getAttribute("wire:updateMode"))
            // But I got error : index.js:31 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$wire' of undefined
            // I see content of doc in browser's console : https://prnt.sc/1sdu4f1
            console.log('updateMode::')
            console.log(updateMode)
```

In my component I have defined :

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

...
class Facilities extends Component
{
    ...
    public $updateMode = 'browse';
```

I just try to get value of $updateMode in JS getSubmitLabel function...

Thanks!

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question where the livewire global object is comming from: you injected livewire scripts in the body of your layout:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    ...
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation

The livewire global object is available via `window.Livewire`. The method you are looking for is probably

```
 Livewire.emitTo(componentName, eventName, ...params)
```

Make sure that the livewire object is actually available when you are calling this method.

For all available methods see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference

To get a component in javascript try:

```
const doc = document.getElementById("myComponent");
window.livewire.find(doc.getAttribute("wire:id"))
```

Comment: Thanks!
With  Livewire.emitTo I found how to sent event to component, but can I to get 
component vars with  Livewire in javascript code?

Comment: @PetroGromovo you can use window.livewire.find(doc.getAttribute("wire:id")).

Comment: What is doc var in your example ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo const doc = document.getElementById("myComponent");

Comment: How can I get JS component-id of my component, which is file 
app/Http/Livewire/Admin/Facilities.php

with declaration :

<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

...

class Facilities extends Component
{
    ...
    public function render()
    {
        ...
        return view('livewire.admin.facilities.container', [
           ...
        ]);
    } // public function render()
I tried different ways, but doc is null in my case

Comment: @PetroGromovo you add id="myComponent" to the root div of your component.

Comment: Pls look at Modified Block  # 2

Comment: @PetroGromovo instead of wire:updateMode use wire:id. Livewire will put a wire:id on the root element of the component. You have to reference that instead of wire:updateMode.

Comment: Cool!, Looks like code     
            var updateMode = window.livewire.find(doc.getAttribute("wire:id"))
            console.log(updateMode.get('updateMode')) 
 works ok!
Could you please point where it is written in docs? I read docs a lot but missed such functionality...
PS: how can I select a piece of code in comments ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo it is documented in https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference in the "Global Livewire JavaScript Object" section. doc.getAttribute("wire:id") is just vanilla javascript to get the wire:id that the find method needs.

Answer (score 0):

> Livewire recommends that you use AlpineJS for most of your JavaScript needs, but it does support using  tags directly inside your component's view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     @livewireStyles
  </head>

<body>
      <p>This is My Component Call </p>
      @livewire('blog-component')

@livewireScripts
     <script>
     Livewire.emit('postAdded') //also write Javascript Hear
     
       document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        // Your JS here.
    })
     </script>
```

> Reference
> https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts
> https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference